# fatal: Not a git repository: blog/../.git/modules/blog

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, silverstripe

i have a small problem with git and i can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. I did git init on the folder but only de silverstripe blog folder doesn't want to get initialised.

error message:
fatal: Not a git repository: blog/../.git/modules/blog

Does anyone have an idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you adding a parent folder as a git repository? Like, is the blog folder a child folder of your git repository, or is blog the folder you're trying to make a repository?

Comment: if this is correct, I think I have the right answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
git remote -v
```

and you should see the details of your repo. If nothing appears then your repo was not created and I recommend you run the following:

```
mkdir directory_name
cd directory_name
git init
```

Then I add the data:

```
git add *
git commit -m "changes I have made"
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a git repo in .git is very risky. I have actually done that myself and it never quite worked out well. Try moving the repo outside of .git into its own folder, then do `git init`

Comment: thank you for your answer. How will i achieve this? since i cant find the .git folder in my mac. I only can remember i did the git init on the main folder. The problem is, it's only the blog folder that doen'st want to work with git.

Comment: .git is generally a hidden folder, so you will probably have to `cd` into the directory manually, or figure out a way to show hidden directories (I don't have a mac, but it's probably a simple google search)

Comment: I'm guessing you have Mavericks: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` is the code to show hidden files in terminal. If you have another version, [this link](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) contains the commands for other versions.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i don't think this fixes my problem.